# Unable to remove the directories using a forfiles script in windows server 2003

Tags: shell, scripting, batch-file

I have prepared a forfiles script to delete the files and folders from one location on multiple servers using the below command. However, the below script does not delete the directories and sub directories but only deletes the files, I tried many switches but nothing works out. Any further help is highly appreciated.

```
WMIC /node:@c:\List of the servers.txt PROCESS CALL CREATE "FORFILES.exe /p %systemroot%\Temp /s /m *.* /d -2 /c \"cmd /c erase @file /q\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
WMIC /node:@c:\List of the servers.txt PROCESS CALL CREATE "FORFILES.exe /p %systemroot%\Temp /d -2 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rd /s @file""
```

To remove folders without question add `/q` to the `rd` command line.

Comment: Again the same error "Invalid verb" I tried some combination like this earlier.

Comment: OK, I did one last modification now. I can't test `wmic`, I have no LAN here. And `forfiles` does work for me on the `%systemroot%\temp` folder.

Comment: ahhh...still the same error message. Forfiles works without wmic but i looking to get that work with wmic to to run on multiple servers. I got tired customizing it at my end so thought of approaching experts :(